# Definite and indefinite articles when introducing a person

Tags: grammar, articles, definite-articles, indefinite-articles

No article is used when introducing a person.

*This ended terribly for **Libyan leader Muammar Qaddafi**; eight years after giving up his nuclear program, the US intervened against him in the Libyan civil war.*

A definite article is used when introducing a person.

*Thomas Homan, **the acting director for ICE**, said the first instance is if parents could not prove family ties to the minor.*

An indefinite article is used when introducing a person.

*Also running in the primary are labor organizer Valerie Ervin, state Sen. Richard S. Madaleno, tech entrepreneur Alec Ross, lawyer Jim Shea and Krish Vignarajah, **a former policy director for Michelle Obama**.*

Does the article difference depend on the sentence structure? Or is there a rule that dictates when to use a definite or indefinite article when introducing a person in writing.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Your third example suggests that Krish Vignarajah is only one of several people who have been policy directors for Mrs Obama. When referring to the one person in a particular post, I don't think there is any rule determining whether to use 'the' or not; it's just a style choice. It would have been OK to put 'This ended terribly for the Libyan leader...'